# GET in a Route - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

what´s the best way if I want to make a GET request in a route?

***api.js***

```
api.route('/guests')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Guest.find(function(err, guests) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(guests);
    });
  });
```

***routes.js***

```
app.get('/export', requiresLogin, function(req, res) {

    /* make a GET request to my api (eg.: 'api/guests') */
    /* and save the 'guests' to a variable              */

});
```

Comment: You can define new `function` that can be called by `api.js` and `routes.js`

Comment: both are different servers ?

Comment: no, it´s on the same server/app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Solution**

Instead of calling internal apis, you can define a controller `guestCtrl.js` and call the function from guestCtrl.js in `api.js` and `routes.js`

**guestCtrl.js**

```
module.exports = {
   getGuests : function(){
      Guest.find(function(err, guests) {
         if (err)
            //handle error
            return [];
         else
            return guests;
       });
   }
}
```

**api.js**

```
//path of guests.js
var guestCtrl = require('guestCtrl.js');

api.route('/guests').get(function(req, res) {
     return guestCtrl.getGuests();
});
```

**routes.js**

```
var guestCtrl = require('guestCtrl.js');
app.get('/export', requiresLogin, function(req, res) {
    var guests = guestsCtrl.getGuests();
    // do whatever you like to do with guests
});
```

**Second Solution**

If you really want to work with internal api, then you can use `request` module.

e.g.

**routes.js**

```
var request = require('request');
app.get('/export', requiresLogin, function(req, res) {
   // you can put the hostname and port here 
   request('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/guests', function(err, body, response){
       var guests = body; // and save the 'guests' to a variable        
   });

});
```